# Facebook API OAUTH - Admin of Page and Owner of APP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I am the page admin of a page and an owner of an app, does that mean I automatically get manage_page permission to the pages I administer?

I basically am seeing that when I do me/accounts and pass my app_token I get access_tokens for  all pages I manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app grants the manage_pages permission then yes your app can get access_tokens for pages. If you go here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin and scroll down slightly there is a section on logging in as pages

Comment: Doesn't the user need to "grant" my app the permission  ?  I am basically seeing that I have access to pages that I have not granted permission to, but I *am* admin to.

Comment: ok,are you sure you didn't also grant the app in question manage_pages permissions via the graph explorer? Have you double checked the permissions in your privacy settings as I cannot recreate the behaviour you describe. Apps I've created cannot read the accounts connection unless I explicitly grant that permission

Comment: So now I understand, you are saying my user account granted the app "manage_page" and that basically means it gets access to any account that I am admin for.  Might want to reword the above and add `manage_pages means the app can get an access token for each of the pages you are an admin for`